# Почему пишет cannot load such file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Создаю свой gem по инструкции описанной здесь: guides.rubygems.org/make-your-own-gem
все создается прекрасно, отрабатывает в irb нормально, как только пытаюсь использовать этот gem в rails пишет

> cannot load such file -- hola

код контроллера:

```
require 'hola'

class TestsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    Hola.hi
  end
end
```

Comment: Так в гемфайл он добавлен?

Comment: Есть ли файл hola.rb в самом геме, по какому пути, если нет, есть ли он в зависимостях?

Comment: @D-side в гем-файл не добавлен, так как пакет установлен локально, без публикации на rubygems.org

Comment: @cheops в самом геме файл есть по пути ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/hola-0.0.0/lib/hola.rb Сам пример примитивнейший, не пойму почему не находит файл. Причем в irb require 'hola' возвращает true

Comment: @Aleksei При подключении гема попробуйте добавить require: false, вот так gem 'hola', require: false. У вас rails s не срабатывает или не находится файл при подключении в контроллере?

Comment: @cheops Добавил require:false, убрал из контроллера require 'hola', теперь стал ругаться на uninitialized constant TestsController::Hola, я так понимаю что  он также не находит файл либы

Answer (score 3):

### "Виноват" [Bundler](http://bundler.io/).

Напоминаю, что это средство для поддержания **предсказуемого набора гемов** в проекте независимо от того, что ещё на машине существует.

Набор гемов определяется в `Gemfile` (при установке, `bundle install`) и в генерируемом из него `Gemfile.lock` (при запуске).

Rails по умолчанию работает в среде, создаваемой Bundler. Если в гемфайле не будет `hola`, то Rails его и не увидит. Добавите — увидит. И нет, для этого не требуется публикация гема на RubyGems. Достаточно того, что он есть локально.

Comment: Добавил в гемфайл hola, но это не помогло, bundler list hola выдает ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/hola-0.0.0

Comment: @Aleksei а `bundle install` сделали?

Comment: @Aleksei очень мало информации, как подключаете в геме файл, через path? Просто гемом, при внесении изменений версию увеличиваете, сам гем удаляете? Мы вам не сможем скорее всего помочь, пока не воспроизведем вашу ситуацию, а для этого нужна хотбы структура вашего гема и способы его подключения.

Comment: @D-side да, сделал bundle install

Comment: @Aleksei и в выведенном списке есть гем `hola`?

Comment: @D-side да, есть там гем hola

Comment: @cheops структуру гема делал по примеру http://guides.rubygems.org/make-your-own-gem/#your-first-gem до момента публикации на rubygems.
в gem - файл добавляю `gem 'hola'` Версию не увеличивал, потому что правок никаких больше не вносил, первоначальный вариант